# apt-get module not being imported into python

Tags: python, linux, import, module, apt

I am trying to install the python-pymssql module into python so that I could connect it my MS database. I have installed the package using apt-get. But when I import into python it tells me " No module named 'pymssql'". Note: I am working on google Colab.

Code:

```
!sudo apt-get install python-pymssql
!apt list --installed 
import pymssql
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try installing it with pip, `pip install pymssql` and check whether it works or not.